# Which font was used

Tags: fonts, icons

Please do you know which font was used in the text "Pelleres".

OR

Samilar font

Image link: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjKD5.jpg)

Comment: Please i attached the image in the link

Comment: what does this have to do with programming? A random google search finds you lots of sites to identify fonts from images, like whatthefont.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

## **euphoric heavy**

HAve a good day

[Put a picture of your font](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/)
Here's a trick, crop the picture. Keep only one letter that is very particular. In this case, the "e" seems very distinct.

Comment: Thanks @user3657688